# How to build all C# projects in VS Code using only one command in tasks.json?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I have the following C# projects:

```
 - Common/Common.csproj
 - WebApi1/WebApi1.csproj
 - WebApi2/WebApi2.csproj
```

And my `tasks.json` is the following:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/WebApi1/WebApi1.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I hit debug selecting the WebApi1 profile, my `launch.json` runs the task `build` (defined in the previous code section) and this tasks builds the `WebApi1.csproj` project alongs with `Common.csproj`, because Common is defined as a dependency.

My question is: how can I use the *same* task to build WebApi1 AND the WebApi2 (and WebApi3, WebApi4, etc.), which means one task to build *all* projects in the repo.

I've tried `"${workspaceFolder}/**/*.csproj"` but this syntax was not accepted.

Comment: You can add all projects to one solution and build the entire `*.sln` file

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for the solution. Changing "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.csproj" to "${workspaceFolder}/mysolution.sln" solved the problem. If you convert your comment to an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Btw, does this syntax is accepted `${workspaceFolder}/*/**/*.csproj`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, no, it gives a syntax error. Only building the solution file worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a possible solution, you can place all your projects into one single solution and specify in a build task, something like that

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/solution.sln"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I'd like to chime in that it's also possible to omit referencing the solution file entirely. As long as you point the path to the folder containing the solution file, you should be good to go. (eg.) `"${workspaceFolder}/<Folder-With-The-Solution-File"`